# Safari 12 and "Prevent cross-site tracking" mode

Tags: authentication, cookies, safari, cross-site

With new approach of Safari browser we have problem to autheticate users on third-site domain:

a) On our webiste `user` log-in and create auth cookie valid for `servicedomain.com`

b) `user` is using our service on his own domain `client.com` by inserting HTML into his code. Eg. `<script src='https://servicedomain.com/app.js' />`

c) Thanks to cookie in (a) step and script pointing at `servicedomain.com` in (b) step, we can distinguish if it is logged `user` (with right cookie) or common guest.

But with Safari 12 and "Prevent cross-site tracking" mode not any more. How to solve this? To tell `user` go to Safari setting and uncheck this mode is not a way.